# Create bigrams using NLTK from a corpus with multiple lines

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to generate bigrams from a corpus with multiple lines. Bigrams are created across line breaks which is a problem because each line represents it's own context and is not related to the subsequent line. That results in semantically incorrect bigrams.

**The corpus**

```
Reeves Acrylfarbe 75Ml Ultramarin 
Acrylfarbe Deep Peach 
Reeves Acrylfarbe 75Ml Grasgrün 
Acrylfarbe Antique Go
```

**Example for problematic bigrams**

> 'Ultramarin Acrylfarbe', 'Grasgrün Acrylfarbe'

**This is the code I am using:**

```
finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(word_tokenize(corpus))
bigrams = finder.nbest(bigram_measures.likelihood_ratio, 100)
```

How can I omit bigrams that span over two lines?

Answer (score 1):

I believe something like this should work:

```
finder = nltk.BigramCollocationFinder.from_documents([
    nltk.word_tokenize(x) for x in corpus.split('\n')])
bigrams = finder.nbest(bigram_measures.likelihood_ratio, 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `split` on '\n' to get a list of lines and process then every line separately and combine the list of bigrams

Comment: had the same idea, but I have no clue how to do this using the BigramCollocationFinder which returns a nltk.collocations.BigramCollocationFinder object

Comment: I assume your `bigram_measures` is an instance of `nltk.collocations.BigramAssocMeasures`. `bigrams` is just a list of tuples/pairs. So you initialise it and then add the new bigrams from each line to it by using `extend`